# Comparing between two pandas code snippets

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve this problem from LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/article-views-i/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=30-days-of-pandas&lang=pythondata

here is my approach:

```
df['id'] = views.loc[views['author_id'].isin(views.viewer_id)]['author_id']
df = df.sort_values('id')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

It doesn't work for some test cases. However, when I changed

```
views.loc[views['author_id'].isin(views.viewer_id)]
```

to

```
views[views['author_id'] == views['viewer_id']]
```

it worked. I can't understand what the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

`views['author_id'].isin(views.viewer_id)` compares each `author_id` to the list of all possible `viewer_id` irrespective of their position in the `viewer_id` column.

`views['author_id'] == views['viewer_id']` performs a  **row-wise** comparison of the `author_id` and `viewer_id`. The result is `True` only if the two values are equal on this particular row.

Here is a quick example to show you the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'author_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'viewer_id': ['C', 'B', 'E', 'F'],
                  })

df['isin'] = df['author_id'].isin(df['viewer_id'])
df['equals'] = df['author_id'].eq(df['viewer_id'])
```

Output:

```
  author_id viewer_id   isin  equals
0         A         C  False   False
1         B         B   True    True
2         C         E   True   False # not equal row-wise but C isin viewer_id
3         D         F  False   False
```

Answer (score 0):

The test is not checking for the authors who viewed any article. They are looking for the authors who viewed  their own article at least once.

That's why the "isin"  won't work. You look for the authors who visited other articles, but have not viewed their own article.

As an example.. The author with id 5 viewed the article with the ID 1, but have not viewed their own article(id 4). Your line will return the author with number 5 too and the test is not looking for them too.

```
 views.loc[views['author_id'].isin(views.viewer_id)]

| article_id | author_id | viewer_id | view_date  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 3         | 5         | 2019-08-01 | False
| 4          | 5         | 6         | 2019-08-02 | True
| 2          | 7         | 7         | 2019-08-01 | True
```

The second line checks only if the author of the article is also the person who viewed their article, which is why this line works.

```
views[views['author_id'] == views['viewer_id']]

| article_id | author_id | viewer_id | view_date  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 3         | 5         | 2019-08-01 | False
| 4          | 5         | 6         | 2019-08-02 | False
| 2          | 7         | 7         | 2019-08-01 | True
```

The author with the ID 7 is also the viewer of the article.